# Need help meshing 2 JQuery Form Plugin's functionalities together

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Let me preface this by saying, I am not a programmer.  So bear with me...my inquiries might sound a little "duh" for the programming masters out there.  Anyway, I am trying to mesh the functionality of two JQuery scripts together.  One script hides parts of the form (in divs) until the user selects from a dropdown the category they want. When the user selects something, the div associated with the selection shows itself. The other script allows the user to add / remove (or in other words clone) the same piece of the form again.  Meanwhile, I would like the the initial dropdown cloned too, allowing the user to pick another or the same category again, and add / remove the piece of the form associated with the category they select.

Its kind of like a store with 3 product categories.  A customer comes in and wants to get a quote for a wide variety of product possibilities from 1 or all 3 product categories all in one inquiry.

So for example, a user selects from the initial dropdown "category_1." The form snippet associated with category 1 shows up and the user fills it in.  The user "adds in" another product, cloning the same form snippet that gets filled out again. Below all of this, the initial dropdown is also cloned and they can pick from lets say "category_2."  The form snippet associated with category 2 shows up, and the user can fill it in and "add in" another category 2 product form snippet, just like they did with category 1.

I hope this made sense.  Anyway, the scripts work fine by themselves.  Its when I use them together, is where I am having problems.

Here is the first script I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#category_1').hide();
    $('#category_2').hide();
    $('#category_3').hide();
    $("#thechoices").change(function(){
    if(this.value == 'all')
    {$("#boxes").children().show();}
    else
    {$("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();}
    });

    $("#thechoices").change();
    });
</script>
```

Here is the second script.  I got it from here: http://vipullimbachiya.com/?p=209.  It uses a separate .js file.  The script below activates it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clone_another").EnableMultiField({
        linkText: "Add Item +",
        removeLinkText: "Remove Item -",
        confirmOnRemove: false,
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my basic markup.

```
<form>
   <div class="clone_another">
       <select id="thechoices">
           <option value="category_1">Category 1</option>
           <option value="category_2">Category 2</option>
           <option value="category_3">Category 3</option>
       </select>
       <div id="boxes">
           <div id="category_1">
           <p>Box 1 stuff...</p>
           </div>
           <div id="category_2">
           <p>Box 2 stuff...</p>
           </div>
           <div id="category_3">
           <p>Box 3 stuff...</p>
           </div>
       </div> 
   </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that the first script works.  It hides and unhides the form snippets according to what is selected in the initial drop down.  What does not work is the ability to clone the form snippet and the initial dropdown so that the user can do another inquiry for another product.  I know I am missing something big here, but I am not knowledgeable enough to know where to look or how to go about solving it.  I greatly appreciate any insight that can be given to me on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It if helps, the form I am actually using this stuff on is here:
www.pentco.com/form.php.

Thanks.